# Does JUri::root() return https on sites that use ssl?

Tags: joomla-api, url, ssl, https

If my site was using ssl, would JUri::root() return a url containing https?

If it didn't, what could I use to return the https equivalent of JUri::root() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/uri/uri.php#L65-L69) - it should return `https`:

```
// Determine if the request was over SSL (HTTPS).
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off'))
{
    $https = 's://';
}
else
{
    $https = '://';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**JUri::root()** returns the Url according to the user access. If the user has accessed Joomla from a https Url, then JUri::root() returns the https root url.

As a side note, to create Urls with no protocol definition, to follow the user access preference, you can create Urls like //www.mydomain.com/blalbla.

Comment: Thanks. I'd thought of using `//www.mydomain.com/blabla` but because of the way I've set up the testing server on localhost it's simpler for me to use JUri::root